# how to trigger title of a element in HTML5 using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the jQuery `focus` event using `trigger()`, but it is not working. All I want to do is trigger a title of a element when page loads.

```js
$('#ahref').trigger('focus');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" title="title" id="ahref">item</a>
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. If you want to programmatically show tooltips you'll need to use a third party tooltip library. Also note that it's `focus`, not `facus`, but it won't work either way

Comment: Typo issue should be "focus" not "facus".

Comment: After correction it is working for me fine. $(function()$('#ahref').trigger('focus');})

Comment: Bear in mind that ’.trigger’ doesn't completely emulate a naturally occurring event. It merely invokes any handlers for the event type.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
       $('#ahref').trigger('click');
    });
```

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment.